# .Add vs .AddWithValue

Tags: mysql, ado.net

I use the .Add method consistently to add parameters to the ParametersCollection. Recently, it was pointed out to me that .AddWithValue is preferred in MySql. [MySQL actively advocate and promote its use](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/)

I accepted this until I realized that the advice was for a particular provider, MySqlConnector. I normally use MySql.Data.MySqlClient. I have not found any information on recommendations on .Add vs .AddWithValue for this provider.

Which is preferred for MySql.Data.MySqlClient?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, any method on a parameter collection that infers the underlying database data type from the supplied value's data type is not preferred at all, for any database system. That counts for both the `AddWithValue` method and the parameter constructors that do not take an explicit database type as an argument.

For all database systems I know, there are several cases where there are no 1:1 mappings from the object/value type to the database type.

It's almost always better to explicitly state the underlying database data type when you create a parameter. That is typically done by supplying a fitting enum value to the parameter collection's `Add` method or the parameter's constructor.

More info: [AddWithValue is Evil | Dan Guzman's Blog](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). (It focuses on SQL Server, but it also applies to various other database systems as well.)

### Edit

It seems that MySQL parameters have a somewhat different story: [Using AddWithValue - MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/). So currently there seems to be no direct objection for using `AddWithValue` with MySqlConnector.

**Personal point of view (at the moment of writing)**

In my opinion, the parameter handling in MySQL/MySqlConnector is somewhat strange. The reason why `AddWithValue` is stated to be OK seems to be the fact, that parameter values are passed in a pretty blunt way anyway (converting numbers to strings, for example). So at first glance, it seems that the MySQL and/or the MySqlConnector command parameter mechanism is not particularly well optimized. This probably has advantages (like flexibility) and disadvantages (like less performance).

Since I am "raised" as a developer in an SQL Server environment, I obviously prefer to be as explicit with type declarations as I can be.

I am curious about any performance differences between using `AddWithValue` and `Add` with MySQL and MySqlConnector, so I will investigate it further. **If performance differences turn out to be small**, I would personally prefer maintainability over performance and stick with explicit database types (thus using `Add` and parameter constructors that take a [`MySqlDbType`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDbType.htm) enum value). These are some of the advantages that I value in that regard:

- I prefer to have a solid, stable, and consistent code base. Using the same mechanisms in data access scenarios is such an example that has my preference, since it simplifies reading and understanding my own code (and thus eases its maintenance).
- Having the underlying database types explicitly specified in the code is a form of self-documentation. Type inference can be nice and concise, but it has its drawbacks as well, so I am always very cautious with it.
- If in the future the MySQL/MySqlConnector parameter type system is optimized, the code will immediately profit from performance benefits without having to revisit and intensively refactor my code base.

Comment: I also refer to https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html
but Caius Jard chided me as follows @Mary "don't use AddWithValue" as a blanket advice should be avoided... "Avoid using AddWithValue if your DB is SQL Server" is better; MySQL actively advocate and promote its use for example

Comment: My question specifically refers to the MySqlConnector vs. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.

Comment: @Mary . . . Yes, indeed. It seems that MySql is a somewhat different story. I have no direct experience with MySql, so I was a little rash with my answer. I will edit it.

Comment: @Mary . . . I have updated my answer. Thanks for the references. I glanced at them briefly, but I will certainly study them in more detail.